# is there an option in interface builder to set an image for a regular UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

UntiL now I only needed bg image, but now I want it also for a regular view that I have, but I want to do in from the interface builder, same as for buttons..

thanks

Comment: Nope, not for a UIView. Any reason not to use a UIImageView?

Comment: It is the same as buttons, which like UIImageViews are a subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no.

You can put an image view behind a regular view, and un-check "opaque" on the view.

You can write code to load an image into a layer and add it to a view.

You can subclass UIView and either add an image view inside it, or override drawRect and draw an image in the background.

But there is no way to put an image into a vanilla UIView in IB.

Comment: This is 100% correct...  But. UIImageView extends UIView.. In other words there is nothing a UIView does that a UIImageView cannot do. So change your view to a UIImageView, turn userInteraction on.. And bobs your uncle, set an image..

Comment: True that. Unless there's more to the OPs need than stated.